# Error creating bean with name : org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I am quite new in the world of Spring Framework and trying to initialize an object 'abcListener' through the Spring which contains an instance variable 'algoMediator' and I am getting following exception.

```
Error creating bean with name 'abcListener' defined in class path resource [eventcreation/integration.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liabilityService' while setting bean property 'algoMediator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'liabilityService' is defined.
```

In Spring XML I have defined bean as follow.

```
 <bean id="abcListener" class="services.integration.AbcListener">
               <property name="algoMediator" ref="liabilityService"/>
</bean>
```

**The Java class is**

```
public class AbcListener 
{
   private AlgoMediator algoMediator;

    public void setAlgoMediator(AlgoMediator algoMediator) {
        this.algoMediator = algoMediator;
    }
}
```

I have checked in project at too many places the intsance variabale bean is defined in same way and as 'liabilityService' is defined in different file but it is not accepting my defination.

**The liabilityService Spring XML is** 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

```
<alias name="liabilityService" alias="algoMediator"/>   
<bean id="liabilityService" class="services.liability.impl.AlgoMediator" init-method="init" >
    <property name="eventLiabilityMonitoringInterval" value="${liability.eventLiabilityMonitoringInterval}"/>
    <property name="fastTrackedSuspensions" value="${ms.fastTrackedSuspensions:false}"/>
    <property name="blurInterval" value="${liability.ms.blurInterval}"/>
    <property name="publishActualOffTime" value="${ms.publishActualOffTime}"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="liabilityDatasource" ref="liabilityDatasource"/>
    <property name="liabilityScaleFactor" value="${liability.scaleFactor:0}"/>
    <property name="sportsWithoutMarketAlerts" value="${alerts.sportsWithoutMarketAlerts}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: post how is your `liabilityService` defined in this different file, post all your Spring xml setup

Comment: The liabilityService is defined as follow

Comment: You should have setters and getters for the bean `algoMediator` in `AbcListener `

Comment: If the bean cannot be found it isn't there. Make sure they are loaded in the same context (or a parent) and not a child...

Comment: can you post all your spring xml files since you mentioned that `liabilityService` is in different file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that init() method exists in AlgoMediator class else remove the init-method="init" declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you create any new injection, go to integration.xml and add the bean, it should solve the issue.

**Example**:

```
public class ExampleClass{
...
@Autowired
ExampleInjection exampleInjection
...
}
```

Add this in `integration.xml`

```
<bean id="exampleInjection"
    class="yourPackageName.className">
</bean>
```